# Pydantic: custom field constraints

Tags: python, pydantic

Using Pydantic, how can I enforce custom constraints? For example, suppose the below function determined if an input was valid

```
def valid(x): 
   if typeof(x) != str: 
      return False 
   else: 
      return x.isnumeric() and len(x)==3
```

Essentially I want strings that only contain numbers and the length must be exactly 3 characters.

Is this possible directly? If not can I instead chain other pydantic methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#annotated-validators), you can do something like that:

```
import typing
import pydantic

from pydantic.functional_validators import AfterValidator

def check(x: str) -> str:
    assert x.isnumeric() and len(x) == 3, f'{x} is not a 3-digit number'
    return x

class Model(pydantic.BaseModel):
    value: typing.Annotated[str, AfterValidator(check)]
```

or, using [constraints](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.StringConstraints), something like this:

```py
import typing
import pydantic

class Model(pydantic.BaseModel):
    value: typing.Annotated[str, pydantic.StringConstraints(pattern=r'^\d{3}$')]
```